# Using OleDbConnection to retrieve Excel sheet names with special characters

Tags: .net, excel, oledbconnection

Hey all,
I am trying to get a list of sheet names from an Excel file using OleDbConnection. (NOTE: This program will run on a server so no option to use office interop classes). So everything works fine with the following code and it bringing back the sheet names:

```
        var dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string sheetName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        }
```

However if the excel sheet name contains a dot “.”, that is converted in a “#”. For example if the excel file has the following sheet names:

```
Sheet.1
Sheet#1
```

The code above will return:

```
"Sheet#1$"
"'Sheet#1$'"
```

And the sheet names are now basically the same. Gets worse!!! when reading data from Sheet.1 as per the following code:

```
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ['Sheet.1$']", connectionString);
```

it will actually read data from "sheet#1" NOT "sheet.1".

Any help will be appreciated.